# How to view latest messages with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, chat

I have no idea about this.

I need to view latest messages from database. (If messages still don't show up to user)

Can I make it without frequent request on the server? (I mean setTimeout with AJAX query)

More: user input and send a message to chat, then chat refreshed and new message show up to all users, which are in this chat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: websockets/longpolling/comet... look them up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas to get you started, though it really is most helpful on StackOverflow to show us what you've tried before.

You have a few things you need to do with this to make it work with ajax and not go with websockets solution (though websockets is probably recommended).

First, you'll need the ajax request to know what the last message the user saw was.

so, assuming you've got a conversation id, and a thread id

1) send the ajax request from the client to the server with the conversation id and thread id. You may need to send your user authentication details across too. We have no idea where you're at at this point.

2) have your server request from the db, all thread ids in conversation where thread id > the id in the ajax request

3) on the client side, take the ajax response and update the client with all the received responses. Update the client with the last thread id so it knows what to send back for the next request.

That should hopefully give you a start.